# iterate through nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How Do I filter and return the users who are enabled ? In my initial approach I'm able to get the all 3 items 
{'name': 'ijk', 'age': 32, 'enabled': 'true'}

```
response = {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "age": 25,
            "enabled": 'true'
        },
        {
            "name": "def",
            "age": 28,
            "enabled": 'false'
        },
        {
            "name": "ijk",
            "age": 32,
            "enabled": 'true'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `[i for i in response['users'] if i['enabled'] == 'true']`

Comment: [u["name"] for u in response["users"] if u["enabled"] == 'true']

Comment: One wonders why the `enabled` field is a string rather than an actual Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

```
enabled_users = []
for user in response["users"]:
    if user['enabled'] == 'true':
        enabled_users.append(user)
```